# UICollectionView freezes the app after tap on an item - Xcode 7, iOS 9, Swift 2

Tags: parse-platform, uicollectionview, ios9, xcode7

I have a weird issue on iOS 9, Xcode official version (no beta): I have a CollectionView with a custom Cell, everything was working fine on iOS 8.x, now the app loads and display cells properly, but if I tap one of them, the app freezes, it doesn't even crash, it just freezes, **and no errors in the console...**

Here's my cellForItemAtIndexPath method:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("PropertyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PropertyCell

var propClass = PFObject(className: PROP_CLASS_NAME)
propClass = self.recentArray[indexPath.row] as! PFObject

// Get details
let imageFile = propClass[PROP_IMAGE] as? PFFile
imageFile?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        if let imageData = imageData {
            cell.pImage.image = UIImage(data:imageData)
} } }

cell.typeActionLabel.text = "\(propClass[PROP_TYPE]!) - \(propClass[PROP_ACTION]!)"

....

cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8

return cell
}


 // MARK: - TAP A CELL TO OPEN CONTROLLER
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var propClass = PFObject(className: PROP_CLASS_NAME)
    eventsClass = eventsArray[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
    
    let pdVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PropDetails") as! PropDetails
    pdVC.propObj = propClass
    navigationController?.pushViewController(pdVC, animated: true)
}
```

I really don't have a clue about this issue, I wish at least the Console Log was showing something...

### Edit

I am putting a breakpoint right before

```
 let pdVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PropDetails") as! PropDetails
```

and going on line by line until the function ends, I get these messages in the console:

```
2015-09-18 16:20:31.894 iResidence[10480:515788] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
2015-09-18 16:20:31.895 iResidence[10480:515801] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
2015-09-18 16:20:43.964 iResidence[10480:515763] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:resource:didFailLoadingWithError:fromDataSource:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```

Any idea about what it is?

Comment: you have no gesture recognizers or `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` delegate methods where something might be happening when you tap on the cells?

Comment: I've thought about it too, anyway there are no Gestures on the controller...

Comment: I've also added the missing didSelectItemAtIndexPath code for your reference

Comment: As of now I don't have iOS 9, so you can just try commenting the code inside `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and just print something there to ensure everything else is fine. Then you can add line by line and find out the actual source of the problem.

Comment: I did that, first I've put just a print("\(indexPath.row)"), and it was working fine, the cell responds to the tap and console gives me the cell's row index. I've added line by line, no error in the console, the app just freezes... :(

Comment: Use the debugger to pause the app in Xcode when it freezes.  Look at the thread or queue display in Xcode's Debug Navigator window to see what's happening, especially on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that

Comment: Ok, i've edited my question, please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was such a stupid one between XCode 7 and Parse SDK, and it took 2 weeks to the Parse guys to figure it out but I can't blame them at all: you cannot put "text" or "txt" word into a TextField, TextView or Label in the Storyboard, otherwise the app freezes once it has to show such Controller.
You can set any text into those views in your Storyboard, but it doesn't have to contain "text" nor "txt".